# Console, Monitor and Buffer Logging

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-commands, logging

Could someone please explain the difference between the console, monitor and buffer logging in Cisco IOS.

```
Console logging: level debugging, 32 messages logged, xml disabled,
                     filtering disabled
    Monitor logging: level debugging, 0 messages logged, xml disabled,
                     filtering disabled
    Buffer logging:  level debugging, 32 messages logged, xml disabled,
                    filtering disabled
```

I think I have an idea that when you telnet into the above device, and issue the command "terminal monitor", the debug messages are shown in the telnet session.Is that right? So when does the console logging and buffer logging used?

Comment: To what network make and model device are you referring? Different manufacturers have different options.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention. Cisco Indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you do not specify, I will assume you mean Cisco IOS.

If you are connected to the console or a VTY line, you can see the messages as they happen with `console` or `terminal` commands, respectively.

Log messages are sent to a buffer in the device, and you can retrieve the buffer to see past messages, no matter how you connect to the device, with the `show logging` command.

You can have different logging levels on each of those three, and you can adjust the size of the logging buffer.

---

Because the logging messages can pop up in the middle of a command you are typing in the terminal or console, you can place the `logging synchronous` command on the lines to restore the the command where you left off after the message is displayed.

Comment: Thanks Ron. So does this mean that all console messages and monitor messages are buffered as well?

Comment: No. The console and terminal messages are immediately sent to the console or terminal. Your application may buffer the lines, but the messages sent to the console or terminal are not buffered. The logging messages that are buffered are controlled separately, but they may overlap with the console and/or terminal messages depending on your configuration.

Comment: Possibly useful if you dont use `logging synchronous`... CTRL+R will give you a new line with the text you were in the middle of typing.